# How to store a dictionary as a separate file, and read the file in a python script to use the variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like some help using python to open a file and use the contents of the file as a variables. 
I have a script that looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt") as f:
    gene_data = {'ham_pb_length':2973, 'ham_pb_bitscore':5664,'cg2225_ph_length':3303, 'cg2225_ph_bitscore':6435,'lrp1_pf_length':14259, 'lrp1_pf_bitscore':28010,}
    for line in f:
            if not line.isspace():
                    bitscore = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']
                    length = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_length']
                    if (2*0.95*length <= bitscore/2 <= 2*1.05*length):
                            print line
```

Where the file "seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt" is a list of gene names ham_pb, cg2225, lrp1_pf, etc. I only included the first 6 values of the dictionary, but it has a total of 600 keys. Each in the form 'name'_length, 'name'_bitscore for the 300 gene names in the file "seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt".

For this reason, I would like to save the dictionary gene_data as a separate text file, and read the file while executing the script. Is there a way to do this. I tried to make a text file "gene_data1.txt" that just included the dictionary. So, the contents of the text file are:

```
gene_data = { 'ham_pb_length':2973, 'ham_pb_bitscore':5664,'cg2225_ph_length':3303, 'cg2225_ph_bitscore':6435,'lrp1_pf_length':14259, 'lrp1_pf_bitscore':28010,}
```

And I tried to use the open function to open the file, so my script looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
gene_data = open("gene_data1.txt", "r")
with open("seqnames-test1-iso-legal-temp.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            if not line.isspace():
                    bitscore = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']
                    length = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_length']
                    if (2*0.95*length <= bitscore/2 <= 2*1.05*length):
                            print line
```

But this just gave me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fixduplicatebittest1.py", line 6, in <module>
    bitscore = gene_data[line.rstrip()+'_bitscore']
NameError: name 'gene_data' is not defined
```

Is there a simple way to make this script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [pickling in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: `pickle` or `json.dump` can help you out.

Comment: as said already `pickle` and `json` is the one option, the other is to print the actual dictionary in a file (a .txt for example) and then use `ast.literal_eval` to read the file as dictionary

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that `NameError: name 'gene_data' is not defined` with that last code block. Instead, you should be getting `TypeError: 'file' object is unsubscriptable` in Python 2, since `gene_data` is the name of a file object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace this line:
`gene_data = open("gene_data1.txt", "r")`

with this:

```
import ast

with open('dict.txt') as f:
    gene_data = f.read()
gene_data = ast.literal_eval(gene_data)
```

but make sure the text file just contains the dictionary, not the assignment of the dictionary:

```
{ 'ham_pb_length':2973, 'ham_pb_bitscore':5664,'cg2225_ph_length':3303, 'cg2225_ph_bitscore':6435,'lrp1_pf_length':14259, 'lrp1_pf_bitscore':28010,}
```

As pointed out by others, allowing your script to **execute** any command in a file can be dangerous. With this method, at least it won't execute anything in the external file, if the contents don't evaluate nicely the script will just throw an error.

Comment: I tried this and received `NameError: name 'ast' is not defined`.

Comment: @Louis, did you import `ast` ?

Comment: I did not, sorry, very new to python. This fixed it for me thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to put the dictionary as you wrote it in its own .py file and import it like any other module.

```
from <filename without .py> import gene_data
```

Then you can use it as if you had typed it in the importing module.

This is very unsafe to do if you do not control the data file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by controlling the data file? I apologize I am very new to python.

Comment: I mean that if someone were to change the data file they could easily break your program by accident or intentionally place malware in it. Therefore you would want to prevent unauthorized access to the file and instruct any users of the danger in changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Either `execfile` or `import` will let you run it as text inside your file.  Be mindful of security implications though.  `import` gives you more control over the execution process, but at the expense of more involved syntax.